# Simple Definite Integral: Check Work Perhaps?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So the problem states:

The density of oil in a circular oil slick on the surface of the ocean at a distance of r meters from the center of the slick is $$ \displaystyle f(r) = \frac{35}{1+r^2}$$ kilograms per square meter. Find the exact value of the mass of the oil slick if the slick extends from $r = 0$ to $r = 15$ meters.

After integrating and the fundamental theorem, isn't this very simply: $$35\arctan(15)$$?

Equating to roughly 52.64 Kgs?

Edit. Thank you to the comment. Final solution comes to $2\pi\log (226)$.

Comment: Remember that this is a *circular* oil slick, not just a straight line. So you have to consider the whole area.